# openfl arguments can't be added

Tags: intellij-idea, haxe, openfl

I've just installed haxe plugin for intellij 14, my openfl project has macros, when I try to add them as arguments in:
In File->Structure->Modules->OpenFL Arguments

when press ok, then open the dialog again, all the arguments I've added is gone!

How can I fix this issue?

**EDIT**

My project compiles just fine in FlashDevelop, where I've added the macros as additional compiler options in the project properties

Comment: not related to your question, but i find intellij 14 to be a bit buggy regarding the haxe plugin - probably out of date i presume. I would stick with intellij 13.

Comment: I could not compile my openFL project, do you think it will work with intellij 13?

Comment: no idea - i use haxe flixel (which does rely on openfl), and it works in intellij 13, but not 14 (and i can't work out what the problem with 14 is yet, but since i don't want to spend that much time on it, i reverted back to using 13).

Comment: does intellij 13 support #if #else #end ? like #if flash ... ?? how would it render the colors? is it ok?

Comment: it has good syntax highlighting, if that's what you're asking: http://i.imgur.com/WHxeF8T.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a little late to the party...

That was a bug in the IntelliJ Haxe plugin itself.  The field data was never saved.  It's fixed now, in release 0.9.9: https://github.com/TiVo/intellij-haxe/releases/tag/0.9.9